# JSON Schema conditional oneOf

Tags: typescript, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I have a oneOf statement in my JSON Schema, but the validator should only allow one of the oneOf options to be selected depending on another value in the schema, for example:

```
If productType === car
Then asset === vehicle

If productType === rocket
Then asset === spaceship
```

I can't work out how to allow this, because my Typescript model looks like this:

```
Product
productType: ProductType;
asset: Vehicle | Spaceship;
```

Schema:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "$id": "myschemaID",
  "type": "object",
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "productType": {
      "type": "string",
      "enum": ["car", "rocket"]
   },
   "asset": {
      "oneOf": [
        { "$ref": "#/$defs/vehicle" },
        { "$ref": "#/$defs/spaceship" }
      ]
    }
}
```

I've, knowing it won't work, have tried a conditional like this:

```
    "asset": {
      "if": {
        "properties": { "productType": { "const": "car" } }
      },
      "then": {
        "$ref": "#/$defs/vehicle"
      },
      "else": {
        "$ref": "#/$defs/spaceship"
      }
    
    }
```

Any help achieving this in schema would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why doesn't it work? Your use of const inside an if statement is exactly correct.

Comment: strict mode: missing type "object" for keyword "properties" at "myschemaID#/properties/asset/if" (strictTypes)

Comment: So turn off strict mode, or add the missing "type" keyword (which isn't actually required, but your implementation thinks that it is, and the author apparently refuses to disable that option from being turned on by default).

Comment: This solved my issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your main issue is that you are missing the `properties` keyword around your property definitions for "productType" and "asset".

In order for the `if`/`then` to work, it needs to be at the same level (or above) as all properties it needs to reference. So, you can't put it in the "asset" schema because then it can't check the "productType" property value in the `if` schema.

Unfortunately, the result is a bit verbose.

```json
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "$id": "myschemaID",

  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "productType": {
      "type": "string",
      "enum": ["car", "rocket"]
    },
    "asset": {}
  },
  "additionalProperties": false,

  "allOf": [
    {
      "if": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "productType": { "const": "car" }
        },
        "required": ["productType"]
      },
      "then": {
        "properties": {
          "asset": { "$ref": "#/$defs/vehicle" }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "if": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "productType": { "const": "rocket" }
        },
        "required": ["productType"]
      },
      "then": {
        "properties": {
          "asset": { "$ref": "#/$defs/spaceship" }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```